# How will the force act outside the stick?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors, statics

**Scenario 1:**

[image]

Here, $P>Q$. $O$ is the center of mass of the rigid and uniform bar/stick. The resultant acts to the right of $\vec{P}$ as $P>Q$.

**Scenario 2:**

[image]

Here, $P>Q$ also. $O$ is the center of mass of the rigid and uniform bar/stick. Now, the problem here is that as $\vec{P}$ and $\vec{Q}$ act at the two ends of the bar/stick, there is no place left to the right of $\vec{P}$. So, where will the resultant of magnitude $(P-Q)$ act?

Comment: Crossposted to [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4409056/768162)

Comment: [You're basically dealing with equivalent transformations](https://engineeringstatics.org/equivalent-tranformations.html)

Comment: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/50269/

Answer (score 1):

The $P-Q$ resultant is in the incorrect position.

Because the rod is subjected to both a net force and a net couple a way of considering the situation is as follows.

[image]

Add forces $Q'$ and $Q''$ acting at the centre of mass $O$ of the same magnitude as force $Q$ as shown in the diagram and repeat by adding forces $P'$ and $P''$ acting at the centre of mass $O$ of the same magnitude as force $P$ as shown in the diagram.

Forces $Q$ and $Q'$ constitute a couple magnitude $Qq$ in an anticlockwise direction and forces $P$ and $P''$ constitute a couple magnitude $Pp$ also in an anticlockwise direction, so the net torque on the rod is $Qq+Pp$ anticlockwise.

The net force acting at the centre of mass of the rod is $P-Q$ and this is just as true for your second diagram.

Comment: Wow! Your solution is very elegant! However, [@Eli's](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/699896/260477) solution is also correct. There he showed that $P−Q$ is acting to the left of $Q$, not at the center of mass, but to the left of $Q$, there is no bar left, so $P−Q$ is acting on nothing?! How does $P−Q$ act at the center of mass of the bar according to @Eli's figure?

Comment: All I can add is that the centre of mass of the rod will undergo a linear acceleration under the influence of the resultant force acting on the rod and also an angular acceleration as a result of the net torque acting on the rod. I have assumed that you are suggesting that the $P-Q$ force in your diagram is the resultant force acting on the rod.

Comment: I see. I understood that from your answer. According to @Eli's answer, the resultant will actually act outside the bar/stick. How is that possible?! Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: I am afraid that I cannot elaborate on what @Eli has done.  Perhaps you should ask the question of the author of that answer?

Comment: "The $P−Q$ resultant is in the incorrect position". Sir, I think that the aforementioned sentence is incorrect. The $P-Q$ resultant is a force that produces the same net force and the same torque on the bar as $P$ and $Q$ combined. In that sense, the $P-Q$ force is in the correct position (in both scenarios 1 and 2). Even though it is in the correct position, it is true, however, that the $P-Q$ resultant in scenario 2 [can't be physically implemented](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/700145/260477). (...)

Comment: (...) On the other hand, in scenario 1, the $P-Q$ resultant can be physically implemented. From that point of view, saying that the $P-Q$ resultant is in the incorrect position is incorrect in my humble opinion (for both scenarios 1 and 2). However, I can agree with you that the scenarios can be usefully described by shifting the $P-Q$ resultant to the center of mass and introducing the two couples as you did. Thoughts?

Comment: If you want, please reply after you've finished your long journey, sir.